# why i get null at relationship field?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa, openjpa

Why if i run this code:

```
Student st = new Student();
st.setFirstName("First");
st.setLastName("Last");
st.setIndexNr("11");
st.setStudentPK(new StudentPK(0, user.getIdUser()));
studentFacade.create(st);

Mail m = new Mail();
m.setContent("con");
m.setRecipient("rec");
m.setIdMail(0);
mailFacade.create(m);

List<Mail> l = new ArrayList<Mail>();
l.add(m);
st.setMailList(l);
studentFacade.edit(st);     // st have mailList property set to l

stud=studentFacade.findByIndex("11"); //after edit and get student he has mailList equal null
```

Why after persist and edit object i get null at property for OneToMany relationship?

---

In database MySql i have `STUDENT` table and `MAIL` table:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `STUDENT` (
  `id_student` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(65) NULL ,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(65) NULL ,
  `index_nr` VARCHAR(45) NULL 
)
ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MAIL` (
 `id_mail` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `recipient` TEXT NULL ,
 `content` TEXT NULL ,
 `sender_student` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_mail`) ,
  INDEX `fk_STUDENT_id_idx` (`sender_student` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_STUDENT`
 FOREIGN KEY (`sender_student` )
 REFERENCES `jkitaj`.`STUDENT` (`id_student` )
 ON DELETE CASCADE
 ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

From database i generate entity in netbeans:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @EmbeddedId
 protected StudentPK studentPK;
 @Size(max = 65)
 @Column(name = "first_name")
 private String firstName;
 @Size(max = 65)
 @Column(name = "last_name")
 private String lastName;
 @Size(max = 45)
 @Column(name = "index_nr")
 private String indexNr;
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "senderStudent",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 private List<Mail> mailList;

 //getters, setters ...

}

public class Mail implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 @Basic(optional = false)
 @Column(name = " id_mail")
 private Integer idMail;
 @Lob
 @Size(max = 65535)
 @Column(name = "recipient")
 private String recipient; 
 @Lob
 @Size(max = 65535)
 @Column(name = "content")
 private String content;
 @JoinColumn(name = "sender_student", referencedColumnName = "id_student")
 @ManyToOne
 private Student senderStudent;

 //getters, setters...
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

I think i forget about `fetch` in `@OneToMany` annotation of `Student` entity. But when i set in to `fetch=FetchType.LAZY` i again get null after edit and and get edited object from database. When  set `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` `mailList` field isn't null. Why ?

Comment: but when i set `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` it's not null. How can you explain it ?

Comment: but i don't have this relation at database so how can i get this from JPA? i don't have relation `STUDENT - ManyToOne - Mail`, but inversely: `STUDENT - OneToMany - Mail` -one student to many mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is at OpenJPA, when i use `fetch=FetchType.LAZY` at some property of entity. The problem was with life cycle of enties. All enties  must be re-attached to the persistence context.

Same problem is here: [OpenJPA - lazy fetching does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864574/openjpa-lazy-fetching-does-not-work?rq=1) and here: [What's the lazy strategy and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869395/whats-the-lazy-strategy-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 0):

You have a unique combination of too much information with too little.

If you are actually running that code, then package it up as a complete, runnable example -- yes, it won't run on another machine unless that machine also has a database setup, but it will tell us everything you're doing instead of just the part that you think is important.

Give us the complete error message, don't tell us what it is.

Two important things to remember about posting a question on a site like this: you don't know what's wrong, so you need to give us complete raw data, not half-analysis.  And it is generally a waste of time for us to just guess at things.

Comment: my error is NullPointerException, i debug my application and find out that after edit student object (add `mailList` to it) and retrive it from database (by find method) `mailList` is set to null

Comment: NullPointerException usually comes with a stack trace, but you seem reluctant to share it.  You might make sure that you aren't running into lazy loading of the field, since you're checking with the debugger.

Comment: I debug my application and i see that `mailList` is null. Why do you want to get a stack trace ? If I run with `fetch=FetchType.LAZY` would I get `mailList` on null ?